# Disconnect a user after 5mins

Tags: php, session

Can somebody please help me on how to disconnect a user (using sessions) after 5mins regardless of being idle or active.thank you 
am coding in php and mysql as the database.

Comment: to destroy the session after 5minutes ..then redirect him to the home page

Comment: mate give us some more info or try to you cookie or set the session expire time in php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user logs on, you could register a session variable for the time, every time a page is loaded, check if 5 minutes has elapsed since logging on.
For example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["loggedin"] && ($_SESSION["timer"]<(time()-(5*60)))) {
logout();

}


function login() {
//do login stuff
$_SESSION["timer"]=time();
}

function logout() {
//do logout stuff
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `session.gc-maxlifetime`:

```
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60*5);
```

Once above line is read by the php interpreter, your session will expire after 5 minutes.

Comment: you have to set `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`. See also my comment on keatchs comment

Answer (score 1):

You can save a timestamp of the last action in the `$_SESSION` array and compare `$timestamp + 300` with the current time.

Just setting the garbage collector lifetime to a low value won't work because the garbace collector doesn't run on every page request.

Comment: This way you don't rely on php configuration settings.

Comment: so what :) The configuration settings are nice but for this small timespans like 5min they're nearly useless because the gc had to run very often...